# Memory and CPU monitoring via Powershell

Tags: powershell, memory, cpu, monitoring

I'm trying to monitor cpu and memory usage for a particular process using powershell. The idea is to schedule it and have it get values at specific intervals, then spit them out to .csv.

So far i've run into 2 cases:

1. The process has a single process ID.
   Code works fine.
2. The process has several subprocesses with their own ID.
   I'd like it to add the values in the final output.  I am not interested in the individual values for each subprocess (ex. every single chrome tab) but the cumulative values for all the subprocesses.

This is the desired output: (if a process has subprocesses, the count should reflect that)

```
Enter the name of the process to monitor: xmrig

21048
------SAMPLES------

TimeStamp    : 2021-04-11 22:32:09
InstanceName : xmrig
CookedValue  : 2289,4108563869    
Count        : 1
Sum          : 15671296

TimeStamp           InstanceName CPU % Count SumMB
---------           ------------ ----- ----- -----
2021-04-11 22:32:09 xmrig        95,39     1 14,95
```

And his is the code:

```
clear

$ProcessName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the process to monitor'
#Write-host $ProcessName
try{
    $ProcessId = Get-Process $ProcessName -ErrorAction Stop | select -expand id
}
catch
{
write-host ("No such process found, try again.") -ForegroundColor Red
$ProcessName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the process to monitor'
}

 $AllProcessIds = Get-Process $ProcessName | select -expand id
Write-Host ""
#Write-Output ("Process "+ $ProcessName + " has ID: "+ $ProcessId )
$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$CPUSamples =@()
$MEMSamples =@()
foreach ($ProcessId in $AllProcessIds){
    Write-Host $ProcessId -ForegroundColor red  
    $CPUSamples += (Get-Counter "\Process($ProcessName*)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples | Select-Object *
    $MEMSamples += Get-Process $ProcessName | Measure-Object Workingset -sum -average  
} 

<# Write-Host "------MEM SAMPLES------"
$MEMSamples
Write-Host "------CPU SAMPLES------"
$CPUSamples #>

$Samples = New-object psobject;
$Samples | Add-Member NoteProperty "TimeStamp" $CPUSamples.Timestamp;
$Samples | Add-Member NoteProperty "InstanceName" $CPUSamples.InstanceName;
$Samples | Add-Member NoteProperty "CookedValue" $CPUSamples.CookedValue;
$Samples | Add-Member NoteProperty "Count" $MEMSamples.Count;
$Samples | Add-Member NoteProperty "Sum" $MEMSamples.Sum;


Write-Host "------SAMPLES------"
$Samples

$Samples.CookedValue | ForEach-object -begin {$CookedValueSum =0} -process {$CookedValueSum+=$_} -end{}

#$Samples| Select-Object TimeStamp, InstanceName, @{Name="CPU %";Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 2)}},Count, @{Name="SumMB";Expression = {[math]::round($_.Sum/1MB,2)}} | Format-Table -AutoSize

$Samples| Select-Object TimeStamp, InstanceName, @{Name="CPU %";Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValueSum / $CpuCores), 2)}},Count, @{Name="SumMB";Expression = {[math]::round($_.Sum/1MB,2)}} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Is there an easier way or am i overcomplicating things?
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your problem is from reading your post. Is it something like this you want to achieve?

```
$Name = "svchost"
$processes = Get-Process $Name
$cpu_cores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors

[PSCustomObject]@{
    Timestamp = (Get-Date)
    InstanceName = $Name
    Count = $processes.Count
    Memory = ($Processes.WorkingSet | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
    CPU = "$([Math]::Round(($processes.cpu | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum / $cpu_cores, 2))%"
} | ft
```

```
Timestamp             InstanceName Count     Memory CPU  
---------             ------------ -----     ------ ---  
4/12/2021 12:27:53 AM svchost         97 2110627840 4.54%
```

Comment: Exactly! So i was overcomplicating things... Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark it as the solution if you don't have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

How about this slight refactor.

```
Clear-Host

$ProcessName = 'idle'

try
{
    $ProcessId = Get-Process $ProcessName -ErrorAction Stop | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty id
}
catch
{
    write-host ("No such process found, try again.") -ForegroundColor Red
    $ProcessName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the process to monitor'
}

 $AllProcessIds = Get-Process $ProcessName | 
 Select-Object -ExcludeProperty id

$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors

$CPUSamples = @()
$MEMSamples = @()

foreach ($ProcessId in $AllProcessIds)
{
    $CPUSamples += (Get-Counter "\Process($ProcessName*)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples | 
    Select-Object -Property '*'

    $MEMSamples += Get-Process $ProcessName | 
    Measure-Object Workingset -sum -average  
} 


$Samples = New-object psobject

$Samples | 
Add-Member NoteProperty 'TimeStamp' $($CPUSamples.Timestamp | 
Select-Object -First 1)

$Samples | 
Add-Member NoteProperty 'InstanceName' ($CPUSamples.InstanceName | 
Select-Object -Unique)

$Samples | 
Add-Member NoteProperty 'CookedValue' $($CPUSamples.CookedValue | 
Measure-Object -Sum).Sum

$Samples | 
Add-Member NoteProperty 'Count' $MEMSamples.Count

$Samples | 
Add-Member NoteProperty 'Sum' $($MEMSamples.Sum | 
Measure-Object -Sum).Sum


Write-Host '------SAMPLES------'
$Samples

$Samples.CookedValue | 
ForEach-object -begin {$CookedValueSum =0} -process {$CookedValueSum+=$_} -end{}

$Samples | 
Select-Object TimeStamp, 
InstanceName, 
@{
    Name       = 'CPU %'
    Expression = {[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValueSum / $CpuCores), 2)}
},
Count, 
@{
    Name       = 'SumMB'
    Expression = {[math]::round($_.Sum/1MB,2)}
} | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

# Results
<#
------SAMPLES------


TimeStamp    : 4/11/2021 8:00:35 PM
InstanceName : explorer
CookedValue  : 0
Count        : 1
Sum          : 167120896




TimeStamp            InstanceName CPU % Count  SumMB
---------            ------------ ----- -----  -----
4/11/2021 8:00:35 PM explorer         0     1 159.38


------SAMPLES------


TimeStamp    : 4/11/2021 8:01:05 PM
InstanceName : runtimebroker
CookedValue  : 0
Count        : 3
Sum          : 262680576




TimeStamp            InstanceName  CPU % Count  SumMB
---------            ------------  ----- -----  -----
4/11/2021 8:01:05 PM runtimebroker     0     3 250.51


------SAMPLES------


TimeStamp    : 4/11/2021 8:01:26 PM
InstanceName : svchost
CookedValue  : 0
Count        : 25
Sum          : 14374760448




TimeStamp            InstanceName CPU % Count    SumMB
---------            ------------ ----- -----    -----
4/11/2021 8:01:26 PM svchost          0    25 13708.84


------SAMPLES------


TimeStamp    : 4/11/2021 8:02:10 PM
InstanceName : idle
CookedValue  : 798.371953662604
Count        : 1
Sum          : 8192




TimeStamp            InstanceName CPU % Count SumMB
---------            ------------ ----- ----- -----
4/11/2021 8:02:10 PM idle             0     1  0.01
#>
```